# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present (CROS)

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax, api

From html page using javascript ajax call am trying to call Login_check api (REST webservice) but am getting error as below.
XMLHttpRequest cannot load

http://184.30.53.119:8080/Automation_test1/TRTS/login/Login_Check. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has a same-origin policy. Which means it cannot request pages on other domains. You have a couple of options to do this, use JSONP or have a php script that you call to query the api.

More information: [Working With and Around the Same-Origin Policy](http://www.sitepoint.com/working-around-origin-policy/)

Comment: Link only answers are not quite recommended. Please provide some examples with explanation.